# Missing annotate output in django when using Case

Tags: python, django, annotate

I'm trying to do some aggregation type work on a model in django using `annotate` and `Case`

So I have something like the following (`q` is already a filtered queryset)

```
q.values(*vals_of_interest).annotate(f1=Case(...))
```

And this works great, the output shows `f1` containing the proper values.  However when I try to add in more items into the annotate, the `f1` just drops out (it doesn't error out, it's just not in the output.  For example

```
q.values(*vals_of_interest).annotate(f1=Case(...), f2=Sum('field_2'))
```

This output just doesn't have `f1` anywhere.  It shows the proper `f2` results, but `f1` simply isn't there.  Is there a limit with `Case` things like this on annotate?

**UPDATE:** I was able to get both values to show up by making `f2` a `Case` as well (with only a default).  This seems hacky and unnecessary but it at least shows the proper results.  Still would be curious if there is a way without doing that